# Animated transformation of Row to Column on layout change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm using a `LayoutBuilder` to layout 2 different widgets in a `Row` if the width is big enough, and in a `Column` if not. I would like to have some animation when the layout changes from `Row` to `Column` and vice-versa. I tried with `Hero` widgets but this didn't work.

Here is a simplified code and the result:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final isWide = constraints.maxWidth >= 600;
        if (isWide) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Hero(
                tag: 'blue',
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              ),
              Hero(
                tag: 'red',
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Hero(
                tag: 'blue',
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              ),
              Hero(
                tag: 'red',
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

How can I have an animation?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets. I think the only solution is to build your custom MultiChildLayout with animation.

Answer (score 1):

For this use-case - try `AnimatedCrossFade`

```
AnimatedCrossFade(
  firstChild: someColumnWidget,
  secondChild: someRowWidget,
  crossFadeState:isWide? CrossFadeState.showFirst  :CrossFadeState.showSecond,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was more thinking about an animation like a hero animation. Where each `Container` moves from one slot to another.

Comment: Yes.... @ValentinVignal Have find the way ? how we can do it ? i want same thing